# Reset supervisor password on Leveno T60

Tags: passwords, thinkpad

I removed the user password on my Lenovo laptop and now it's asking me for a supervisor password I never set.
Apparently this password is kept in some sort of non volatile memory and cannot be cleared by resetting the CMOS, which I have already tried.
Does anyone know what this password may be? My model is a T60. I saw another procedure, but it involved an eeprom and other complicated equipment, I do not have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the supervisor password, if unset is the same as the password you removed, just capped at 7 characters. Mine was 9 characters.

Comment: I would say that this is a ridiculous design decision.  I remembered running into a similar situation several years ago -- I believed that I hadn't set the supervisor password for my T43, but the BIOS was constantly asking for it ever time I entered the set-up screen.  I sent the ThinkPad to a third-party repairman who replaced the EEPROM on it and removed the supervisor password.

Answer (score 1):

with most modern laptops, simply removing the CMOS battery does not clear the the password (this would be to easy in case of loss or theft).

you can contact Lenovo technical support for asistance in the matter (which is what I would do) or resort to some 3rd party solution like the PC8394T Programming Tools and 'hack' the BIOS which involves the EEPROM you have already mentioned, a chip reader and plenty soldering.

Comment: Hi Matt, Lenovo tech support is your only answer unless you want to delve in with a soldering iron and some hardcore effort.